# which event to use to the attribute values of the pre-selected tab in ui jquery tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i have a ui tabs of jquery inside a dialog box that pops out whenever i click somewhere in the main page.

so when it pops out. the first tab is active. now my question is, how to get the first tab's properties?. because in the succeeding tabs, I was able to get the properties by using the `activate` event of this jquery ui
like this

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    activate : function(event,ui){
       alert(ui.newPanel.find(".row #button").attr("id"));}
 });
```

that one works when I click the other tabs. it will also work if I go back to the first tab after clicking the other tabs. but by default.. how to get the first tab? if i haven't clicked yet the other tabs?

Comment: Did you try `create` event, `ui.tab`, *The active tab*

Comment: do you have any samples for this the create event ?, i mean for getting the first tab when the dialog pops up?

Comment: Yep: https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-create

Comment: yes, I saw that sample before..but the thing is, what event should I attach to the create event?..because, when my dialog pops out, the first tab in the ui tab is by default selected

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: this one.. https://jsfiddle.net/7ft9hk65/ .. i wonder how to alert the first tab ...the snippet i provided will work on the first tab "only after clicking the other tabs".. i want to be able to get the first tab one the tabs are loaded, because by default it's preselected as you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by getting that active tab on first load

```
 var active = $("#dialog-content #tabs").tabs("option","active");
```

then check if it's really the first tab

```
if(active == 0)
{
   var widget = $("#dialog-content #tabs").tabs("widget");//get the tab
   //do you thing
   //widget.find(".row #element").val()
}
```